# How to select namespace value via XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to get the `xmlns:attr` attribute value from this XML using XPath. I can't seem to get it.

```
<a:b xmlns:attr="value">
</a:b>
```

This is from the root node.

I've tried just about every combination, but I can't seem to find anything that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting aside the distraction of the undeclared `a:` namespace, let's instead use this example:

```
<b xmlns:attr="value"/>
```

**Note**:  Your name choice of `attr` belies the fact that in the above XML, `attr` is not an ***attribute*** but rather is a ***namespace prefix***.

### XPath 1.0

**Use the `namespace` [axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes):**

```
/b/namespace::attr
```

will evaluate to

```
value
```

### XPath 2.0

According to [XML Path Language (XPath) 2.0 (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-in-scope-namespaces):

> In XPath Version 2.0, the namespace axis is deprecated and need not be
>   supported by a host language.

**Instead, use the [`namespace-uri-for-prefix()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-namespace-uri-for-prefix):**

```
/b/namespace-uri-for-prefix('attr',.)
```

will evaluate to

```
value
```

Comment: Be careful however. You source should not depend on the prefix ("attr") but only on the actual namespace ("value"). Prefixes can change and are optional for elements.