# PL/SQL extract XML namespace value

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I have the XML file with this ROOT tag

```
<DEFeatureDataset xsi:type='typens:DEFeatureDataset'
                    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
                    xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
                    xmlns:typens='http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.1'>
```

How can I extract the 3rd namespace value "http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.1" in a select statement using xml query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [How to select namespace value via XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28822216/1509264):

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY(
         '/DEFeatureDataset/namespace-uri-for-prefix("typens",.)'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( xml ) RETURNING CONTENT
       ) AS typens
FROM   table_name;
```

or

```sql
SELECT x.*
FROM   table_name t
       OUTER APPLY XMLTABLE(
         '/DEFeatureDataset'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( t.xml )
         COLUMNS
           typens VARCHAR2(100) PATH './namespace-uri-for-prefix("typens",.)'
       ) x
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( xml ) AS
SELECT '<DEFeatureDataset
  xsi:type="typens:DEFeatureDataset"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:typens="http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.1"></DEFeatureDataset>' FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

> ```
> | TYPENS                                  |
> | :-------------------------------------- |
> | http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e0b1da8e03c937f48304d3b430d102de)*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  Both solutions worked.  I prefered the first one.  Just had to wrap the return value inside XMLCast; like so....                              

         SELECT XMLCast(XMLQUERY(
         '/DEFeatureDataset/namespace-uri-for-prefix("typens",.)'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( Definition ) RETURNING CONTENT
       )AS VARCHAR2(100)) AS typens